# how to make chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that displays the content of an "https" web page in the popup window.
So far I have been able to see the default popup window that I place in the `manifest.json` file.
I am doing something like this in my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Rewards",
    "description": "Validate Identify",
    "version": "1.1",
    "permissions": [ 
        "identity",  "identity.email"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16":"/images/icons/myRewards16.png",
            "32":"/images/icons/myRewards32.png",
            "48":"/images/icons/myRewards48.png",
            "128":"/images/icons/myRewards128.png"
        }        
    },
        "icons":{
            "16":"/images/icons/myRewards16.png",
            "32":"/images/icons/myRewards32.png",
            "48":"/images/icons/myRewards48.png",
            "128":"/images/icons/myRewards128.png"
}
```

I was looking at the chrome extensions documentation and it says that it could be done using the `action.setPopup()` method.
I'm a bit of a novice on the subject
and I do not know the correct way to add the method, could you please guide me.

Comment: Why do you want to show a web page in your extension popup? Isn't that what regular browser tabs are for?

Comment: yes sir, what happens is that my extension should show a documentation, but that documentation is hosted on a web page

Answer (score 1):

Only html in the extension package can be specified with `chrome.action.setPopup()`.

This example works if web page allows iframe.
[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hogehoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body style="min-width:800px;min-height:600px">
  <iframe id="iframe" width=800 height=600 src="https://nory-soft.web.app/"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

If not allowed, an error will result.
[image]

This example will also work if the web page does not allow iframe, but clicking the link will result in an error. Layouts often fall apart.
[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hogehogehoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body style="min-width:800px;min-height:600px">
  <iframe id="iframe" width=800 height=600></iframe>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const elmIframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

const url = "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/";

fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors'
})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    }
    throw new Error('Response was not ok.');
  })
  .then(data => {
    html = data;
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/html" });
    elmIframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: I still don't understand why anyone would want to open a website in an extension popup. That would mean creating a browser inside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This example displays the extension's documentation in a new tab.

popup.js

```js
const url = "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/";

chrome.tabs.create({ url: url }, () => {
  window.close();
});
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think @AndresVela wants to display the web page in the popup, not in a new tab.